# Restful service with WebAPI and MVC as client architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am building a restful web service api using ASP.NET WebAPI. I'll be consuming it with MVC as a web application and eventually in a mobile app. I want to make the api standalone and not couple it with the MVC application.
I am having trouble figuring out how the authentication should be structured. I need the api to be consumable only from a specific sources(the web app and the mobile app). However, I dont know how to link the authentication in the WebAPI with the MVC one. New users should register in the MVC and their auth info should be supplied to the WebAPI. I'm using the Individual accounts Identity system for the project.

In short, how to use the same authentication for both the Api and the Client? Should they be deployed to the same domain?

Answer (score 1):

I recently did something similar.

I think you have 2 issues here:

1. You want to only accept Web API requests from known sources.
2. You want to authenticate the user.

For number 1:

You want to add authentication to the Web API Request. This could be basic authentication, but it shows the call is coming from a known application. By using this, you know where the call is coming from. Despite what you read, Basic Authentication is ok, but only if the call is over a TLS (HTTPS) connection . Otherwise the call could be seen and the authentication could be used in a replay attack.

For number 2:

You could have a method that the user can call, such as a login request, where the user can be authenticated and, if successful, issue them with a token. JWTs (Javascript Web Tokens) are one token that you can use. Then the token can be sent with each subsequent call. However, please bear in mind that they can be a pain to use!

It depends on how tight your security needs to be. It might be that basic authentication, along with TLS might be enough for you.